# How to use DFLUX subroutine on multiple surfaces in Abaqus?

Tags: subroutine, abaqus

I am simulating a 2-dimensional additive manufacturing process where there is **a moving Gaussian heat source on top of a powder layer.** The heating step is followed by a cooling step after which a new powder layer is added and the same heat source moves on top of this new layer. 
The 
[image shown here is a schematic representation of my domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9BP.png)

This means the **same heat source** is acting on **two different surfaces at different steps**
In the results, the DFLUx subroutine is not working on the surfaces at different time steps. I have attached my DFLUX subroutine here

```
SUBROUTINE DFLUX(FLUX,SOL,KSTEP,KINC,TIME,NOEL,NPT,COORDS,
 1 JLTYP,TEMP,PRESS,SNAME)    
  INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
  DIMENSION FLUX(2), TIME(2), COORDS(3)
  CHARACTER*80 SNAME  
  REAL Pi, Exp
  REAL Power, Efficiency, Effective_Power, Sigma, Peak_Flux
  REAL Speed_Of_Beam
  REAL Center_Of_Beam1, Center_Of_Beam2, Processed_Length1, Processed_Length2
  REAL Bottom_Limit1, Bottom_Limit2, Top_Limit1, Top_Limit2
  REAL Position1, Position2
  REAL BeamContrib

  double precision temperature
  double precision gamma_Al, X_Al
  double precision p_Al, M_Al
  double precision enthalpyEvAl
  double precision gamma_Ti, X_Ti
  double precision p_Ti, M_Ti
  double precision enthalpyEvTi
  double precision AlContrib, TiContrib
  double precision fracLiquid
  double precision VaporContrib
  double precision SumFlux

  Pi = 3.14159265D0
  Exp = 2.71828183D0

 **beam operation parameters
  Power = 360D0
  Efficiency = 0.9D0
  Sigma = 0.00025D0
  Speed_Of_Beam = 0.4D0
  Effective_Power = Power * Efficiency
  Sigma_Max = (1 / (Sigma * ((2 * Pi)**0.5)))
  Peak_Flux = (Effective_Power / ((Sigma * (2 * Pi)**0.5)))

  **model geometry parameters
  Start_Of_Beam = - 3 * Sigma
  Processed_Length1 = Speed_Of_Beam * (TIME(2)-0.01)
  Center_Of_Beam1 = Speed_Of_Beam * (TIME(2)-0.01) + Start_Of_Beam
  Processed_Length2= Speed_Of_Beam * (TIME(2)-0.426875)
  Center_Of_Beam2= Speed_Of_Beam * (TIME(2)-0.426875)+Start_Of_Beam

  ****COORDINATES DEFINED

  X = COORDS(1)
  Y = COORDS(2)
  Y1=0
  Y2=0.0002

  Position1 = (X - Center_Of_Beam1)
  Position2 = (X - Center_Of_Beam2)
  Bottom_Limit1 = Center_Of_Beam1 - 3 * Sigma
  Bottom_Limit2 = Center_Of_Beam2 - 3 * Sigma
  Top_Limit1 = Center_Of_Beam1 + 3 * Sigma
  Top_Limit2 = Center_Of_Beam2 + 3 * Sigma

****NORMAL DISTRIBUTION FLUX DEFINED

  IF (kstep.EQ.2.AND.Y.EQ.Y1) THEN
    IF (X.LE.Top_Limit1.AND.X.GE.Bottom_Limit1) THEN
        Sigma_Function = Sigma_Max * Exp**(-1 * (Position1) **2 / (2 * Sigma * Sigma))

    BeamContrib = (Sigma_Function) * Peak_Flux
  ELSEIF (kstep.EQ.6.AND.Y.EQ.Y2) THEN
    IF (X.LE.Top_Limit2.AND.X.GE.Bottom_Limit2) THEN    
      Sigma_Function = Sigma_Max * Exp**(-1 * (Position2) **2/ (2 * Sigma * Sigma)) 
      BeamContrib = (Sigma_Function) * Peak_Flux        
  ELSE
      BeamContrib = 0.D0
  ENDIF
  ENDIF
  ENDIF   

 ***Vapor param defined (contributing for Al evaporation)
  temperature = sol
  if (temperature <= 1983.15) THEN
    gamma_Al= 0.2
  ELSE IF ( temperature <= 2398.15 ) THEN
    gamma_Al= 0.2 + 0.3*(temperature-1983)/(2398.15-1983.15)
  ELSE
    gamma_Al= 0.5
  endif

  X_Al = 0.101954875
  p_Al= 133.22 * 10**(-16450.0/temperature+12.36-1.023*LOG10(temperature))
  M_Al= ( 0.02698153 /2 /Pi /8.314462 /temperature)**0.5
  enthalpyEvAl=13870000
  AlContrib = gamma_Al * X_Al * p_Al * M_Al * enthalpyEvAl

  gamma_Ti= 1.0
  X_Ti = 0.862
  p_Ti= 133.22 * 10**(-23200.0/temperature+11.74-0.66*LOG10(temperature))
  M_Ti= ( 0.047867 /2 /Pi /8.314462 /temperature)**0.5
  enthalpyEvTi= 8878768.254
  TiContrib = gamma_Ti * X_Ti * p_Ti * M_Ti * enthalpyEvTi

  if (temperature >= 1868) THEN
    fracLiquid= min((temperature-1868)/30.0,1.0)
    VaporContrib = -1.0 * fracLiquid * (AlContrib + TiContrib)
  else
    fracLiquid= 0.0
    VaporContrib=0.0
  endif

  SumFlux = BeamContrib + VaporContrib

  endif

  FLUX(1) = SumFlux

  RETURN
  END
```

The DFLUX subroutine is not acting on the surfaces in different steps. Any help on debugging the errors in the subroutine will be appreciated.